# Wie bezieht man sich im Satz auf das Pronomen "man"?

Tags: colloquial

Sagen Sie mir bitte, welche Variante mit dem Pronomen *man* verwendet werden würde?

> Je ruhiger man sich verhält, desto komfortabler geht **einem/ihm/dem** es.

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

Das Pronomen *man* dekliniert man *man, –, einem, einen*. (Der Genitiv wäre *eines*, er wird aber nie verwendet.)

> Man ist ruhig.
>
> Das Glück kommt zu einem.
>
> Sie sieht einen.

Wenn du *man* in der zweiten Satzhälfte beibehalten willst, ist die richtige Wahl also:

> Je ruhiger man sich verhält, desto komfortabler geht es einem.

Ich habe die Reihenfolge der Satzglieder umgestellt. Es muss *es einem* heißen. *Einem es* würde *es* viel zu sehr betonen.

Und *ihm* und *dem* sind grammatisch ebenso richtig. Es ist dann bloß nicht dieselbe Person wie *man* gemeint.

> Je ruhiger man sich verhält, desto komfortabler geht es ihm.
>
> Je ruhiger man sich verhält, desto komfortabler geht es dem.